# chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener causing this error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onActivated')

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a chrome extension that start a timer when we open a new tab and then display the time we have spend on this tab when clicking on a button.

But when i actually test my extension , i get this error message on the developer console and the error message refer to a line in my background.js which is a chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener

**This is my background.js code :**

```
console.log(typeof chrome.tabs)
if (chrome.tabs?.onActivated) {
  chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(activeInfo) {
    //console.log("handleActivated")
    //console.log(typeof chrome)
    //let start = new Date()
    //console.log(typeof start)
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({data: "start"});
    console.log(typeof chrome.tabs)
    console.log("message sent !")
  });
}
else {
  console.log("Issue found")
}

});
```

**This is my content script :**

```
let stop_t = document.getElementById("stop")
let stop , start

console.log("Started")

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.data === "start") {
        console.log("message received")
        start = new Date()
        console.log("message arrived")
    }
    else{
        console.log("error message not arrived")
    }
});
  
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    stop_t.addEventListener("click", function() {
        stop = new Date();
        console.log("message received ?")
        if (start) {
            let mili = stop.getTime() - start.getTime();
            let all_sec = mili * 0.001;
            let sec = Math.round(all_sec) % 60;
            let min = Math.floor(all_sec / 60);
            let time = "min :" + min + "      sec :" + sec;
            alert(time);
        } else {
            alert("Timer is not started yet.");
        }
    });
    
});

**Manifest.json :**
```

{
"manifest_version" : 2,
"name" : "Time tracker",
"version" : "1.0.1",
"description" : "Keep track of your time on every tab ",
"permissions": ["tabs", "runtime"],

```
"content_scripts": [{
  "matches": ["*://*/*"],
  "js": ["index.js"],
  "run_at": "document_end"
```

}],

```
"browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Time tracker", 
    "default_popup": "popup.html"  
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  }
```

}

```
I first tried searching for people having similar issue and i did find some having this same error but not with the "chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener" and i didn't manage to take advantage of the solution to resolve my issue .

I also tried doing some console log and the only things that log out are the console.log in the chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener which log out every time i open a new tab. All the console.log in my content script never log out.

Also, when i click on the button , i only have this alert : alert("Timer is not started yet.") suggesting that start is undefined.


***UPDATE :*** 

After further research , the issue is that the "chrome.tabs" in the background.js is **undefined** and this lead to an issue because the script has to deal with :
undefined.onActivated.addListener --> This is what lead to the error 


But i really don't why the chrome.tabs is undefined , need help on this.
```

Comment: I get an error when I install your extension.
`Permission 'runtime' is unknown or URL pattern is malformed.`

Comment: 1) You probably look at `chrome://extensions` list of errors, not at the [background.js console](/a/10258029). The list shows old errors, which are no longer relevant, so you need to press the trashcan icon or `Clear all` button to remove them. 2) To send to a tab you need chrome.tabs.sendMessage with a tab id, not chrome.runtime.sendMessage.

Comment: @wOxxOm 1)no i don't think so , the console actually display error that are happening right now. 2) I actually don't want to send the tab info, i only want to send a value when somoene open a new tab

I made an update on my question due to further understanding of the problem, i think it will help you undestand better the issue

Comment: Since the posted code is correct except the sendMessage mistake, the only other explanation is that you access chrome.tabs in some other place like the content script or maybe a page opened from localhost or from a file.

Comment: @wOxxOm I just updated my code , as you can see i only access the chrome.tabs from my background.js

Comment: In that case it's a bug in Chrome because chrome.tabs can't be undefined in a background script, you can report it in https://crbug.com.